# Script to add users to a group and system

Tags: scripts, users, groups

I have been trying to make a script using vim to automate the creation of users and adding them to a group. I have tried multiple other sites and have found nothing. How would I do this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain i) what you have so far ii) which part is giving you trouble?  iii) what users do you want to add to what groups? iv) why is vim relevant? Isn't the question about writing scripts? Any editor would do.

Answer (score 0):

Using `vim` to add users/groups (by editing `/etc/passwd`,`/etc/group`,`/etc/shadow`,`/etc/gshadow`, ...) is The Really Hard Way.

I call it "Really Hard" for two reasons.

First, we already have tools to do that (and they do ALL the steps, and are upgraded as needed). Read `man useradd` and `man adduser`. One can use these tools to create a userid with an expired, empty password. This leads to NO password for initial login, and mandatory user password selection.

Second, using `vim` in scripts is major overkill. Read `man ed` for a simple editor that will probably serve your needs.